# docker compose up throws an error "stat [compose.yaml]: no such file or directory"

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose

On ubuntu 23.04 (GNU/Linux 6.2.0-24-generic x86_64), I have encountered an error while trying to run docker compose.

```
$ sudo docker compose -f /containers/watchtower/watchtower.yaml up -d
stat /containers/watchtower/watchtower.yaml: no such file or directory
```

The compose.yaml exists.

```
$ ls -l /containers/watchtower/watchtower.yaml 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bob bob 1373 Jul 10 21:39 /containers/watchtower/watchtower.yaml
$ stat /containers/watchtower/watchtower.yaml 
  File: /containers/watchtower/watchtower.yaml
  Size: 1373        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 0,29    Inode: 117329      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/   bob)   Gid: ( 1000/   bob)
Access: 2023-07-10 21:47:36.158533071 +0000
Modify: 2023-07-10 21:39:20.331301456 +0000
Change: 2023-07-10 21:39:20.331301456 +0000
 Birth: 2023-07-10 21:39:20.331301456 +0000
```

some background info

```
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.17.2
$ python3 --version
Python 3.11.2
$ uname -r
6.2.0-24-generic
$ cat /containers/watchtower/watchtower.yaml 
---
version: "3.8"
services:
  watchtower:
    image: containrrr/watchtower:latest
    container_name: watchtower
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - WATCHTOWER_CLEANUP=true
      - WATCHTOWER_INCLUDE_STOPPED=true
      - WATCHTOWER_REVIVE_STOPPED=false
      - WATCHTOWER_LABEL_ENABLE=false
      - WATCHTOWER_MONITOR_ONLY=false
      - WATCHTOWER_TIMEOUT=300
      - WATCHTOWER_SCHEDULE=0 16 2 * * *
```

Could someone give me a pointer on what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out what the problem was.

I had installed docker through snap.

docker compose works once I have replaced the snap version with the native version.